# Dropping a first person subject pronoun in a conditional sentence

Tags: verbs, pronouns, verb-agreement, objects, subject-drop

Is it possible to drop the 'I' before the verb in a sentence where the object comes before the verb?
A few examples are:

If my journey (I) restart, then I do waste my time.

If my folders (I) delete, then I do lose my files.

This sentence structure strikes me as being unorthodox. I'd like to know whether or not it is acceptable, and if so, in which contexts.

Comment: It could work in poetry. Otherwise, could you shift the order a bit to get to a logical order: *If restarting my journey, I* or *If deleting my folders, I*?

Comment: Weird at best..

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'm using it in a poem. Having it in logical order works against the flow of the piece.

Comment: In a poem, all bets are off. If the reader has to think about it a while, and that is your intention, go for it. The tone is the high tone of a prayer.

Comment: The sentences are equally strange with or without the *I*. I would be more inclined to replace the *I* with *should*. Also, poetically, I would expect *do I* rather than *I do*. (1) *If my journey **should** restart, then **do I** waste my time.* (2) *If my folders **should** delete, then **do I** lose my files.*

Comment: @YosefBaskin What makes something be in "the high tone of a prayer"?

Comment: @JasonBassford **do I** seems interesting. Using 'should' seems to me to have the effect of making the first person actor passive.

Comment: @SaidBisher In hindsight, it's the combination of **I restart** (for example) with **I do** that sounds a bit clunky to me. I don't have nearly as much of an issue in terms of poetic flow if **I restart** is combined with **do I**. Also note that if you just say **journey restart**, you're dropping a syllable. The use of either **I** or **should** gives a more balanced metre between what comes before the comma and what comes after it. (Although that's only my personal opinion.)

Comment: The high tone of a prayer is the grand quality of holy books, the Psalms, for example. Lofty, spiritual, pure, not concerned with pettiness.

Comment: In my opinion the examples given make sense as they are - an unusual but clear wording, perfectly appropriate in a poem. But they don't make sense if you drop the I's shown in parentheses - they would still be understood, but would sound wrong.

Comment: @Jason Bassford. I don't have an academic understanding of metre but to my ear, in the context of the lines before it, it sounds better without the I. The part before the comma sounds shorter than that which comes after to create a sort of 'back and forth'. This is used in the line above it as well. Is a comma necessary to emphasise the 'then' and prevent it from sounding like a question or is the lack of a question mark enough? "If my journey restart, then(,) do I waste my time."

Comment: @SaidBisher Since it's a poem, the lack of a comma *before* doesn't matter. (Even in regular writing, despite the comma being more common, it's still a matter of style to include it or not.) But I certainly don't think that *then* should be bracketed between commas—but, again, that's just me personally. Note that even some questions don't use question marks: "I've lived on the moon for the last 5 years." "Really." In that exchange, *really* is a kind of dismissive rhetorical question. The person doesn't need or expect it to be answered, because they already know the statement has to be false.